# ¿Cómo puedo usar un textarea dentro de un echo php?

Tags: php, html

Estoy aprendiendo php y soy bastante novato por lo cual si me dan una mano se los agradecería, estuve tratando que en ves de input sea textarea, pero me genera error en el navegador.

```
<?php 
  echo "<input type='text' id='post_tags' 
   placeholder='".esc_html__('Agregar', 'clasi')."' 
   name='post_tags' value='";
    $posttags = get_the_tags($current_post);
    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
         $tags_list = $tag->name . ', ';
         echo esc_html($tags_list);
        }
    }
    echo "' size='' maxlength='' class='form-control form-control-md'>";?>
```

Comment: El text area que estas intentando imprimir  debe tener algún valor ?  es decir le asignas el valor de una variable ?

Comment: si es esto, en realidad esta parte es para editar lo que cargó en otro template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo el código que has escrito. Ni el por que tienes un `foreach`

pero si quieres imprimir un `textarea` desde un `echo`  es así :

```html
<?php 

echo "
<textarea id='w3review' name='w3review' rows='4' cols='50'> Aqui el valor  </textarea> ";

?>
```